# I cannot autoload my class using psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php

I am learning auto loading my calss using psr-4 but I have no luck,here is my folder structure

[image]

Here is the code inside my "Employee.php"

```
   namespace app\Employee;


class Employee
{
   public function __construct(){
       echo "hello employee";

   }

}
```

and in my index.php

```
use app\Employee;


  $emp = new Employee;
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "Employee\\":"app/Employee"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In composer Employee\\ doesn't match your app\Employee namespace. It should probably just be "app\\":"app". In index.php you're instantiating app\employee, while with your structure you'd have to do "use app\Employee\Employee". I'd guess the folder "Employee" should be "Model", "Controller", or similar.

Comment: @JimL what do you mean should be Model

Answer (score -1):

Your current autoloader, expects that the "Employee" namespace is mapped within the "app/Employee/" directory.

With your setup, you would need to add in index.php

```
use Employee\Employee;

$emp = new Employee();
```

And the actual namespace of Employee.php would be:

```
namespace Employee;

class Employee {}
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it changes too much. Why change the namespace of all classes in `app/Employee` and in all `use` clauses in every other part of the code if you can simply fix it with a change in `composer.json`?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
use app\Employee;

$emp = new Employee;
```

to:

```
use Employee\Employee;

$emp = new Employee();
```

Comment: This will still fail to load the class, because it is in namespace `app\Employee`. You are suggesting it to be in `Employee\Employee` instead.

Answer (score -1):

From your code in `Employee.php`:

```
namespace app\Employee;
```

This is the namespace you have to use if you want to access the class.

PSR-4 in Composer works like this:

```
"autoload":{"psr-4": { "Namespace\Prefix":"a/path"}}
```

When loading a class "Namespace\Prefix\Class", Composer will see the PSR-4 entry and compare if the class being loaded starts with that Prefix. It does! Now it remove the detected prefix from the classname, and treats the rest as a path and file name relative to "a/path".

So the remainder of that class is "Class", and because there is no backslash left, this directly is the filename "Class.php" (note the uppercase filename). This file is searched in "a/path/Class.php".

For your situation, you almost did everything right - the only thing: Your namespace prefix in `composer.json` is not `Employee\` - you gave the correct prefix in your code above.